# How to save text to the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, input, save

How can i achieve this using jQuery. I have two text inputs on the page, so when the users has entered text and left the input field, for that text to be inserted into the DOM so i can access it?

EDIT:

To clarify i have this:

```
Expected Delivery Date: <input id="exp" type="text"></input>
```

What i'm trying to do is print the contents of the page, but its not printing this input value?

This is the only input i need from the user so i wanted to avoid having to submit the form just for one input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs are already in the DOM, you can get their value using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like this:

```
var myValue = $("#inputID").val();
```

You may need to use [a different selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) but the idea stays the same, it's `$(selector).val()`, or possible `this`, for example if you want the value when the user leaves:

```
$("input").blur(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qETEe/).

Comment: thanks for this, if you see my edited question, this explains my problem better

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('.my-input-fields').blur(function() {

   var div = $('<div/>');
   div.html( $(this).val() );

   $('#DOMplaceOfEntry').append(div);

});
```